# global declarations illegal in verilog 2001 syntax Task

Tags: verilog

I've got a verilog file which all I want to have in it is a task that does some maths which I am then `include "maths.v"` in another file and calling the task by writing `mathsfunction;` in a `initial begin - end` block in the other file which should run the task at that point if I understand correctly, the code is below:

Maths.v

```
task mathsfunction;
reg [0:31]   x;
reg [0:31]   y;
reg [0:31]   z;
begin
    x = $urandom;
    y = $urandom;
    z = x + y
end
#200    
endtask
```

I'm getting one compile error which is on the first line `task mathsfunction;` which is `Global declarations are illegal in Verilog 2001 syntax.` From what I've learnt so far, having a verilog file which is just a task (not a module, I dont want it to be a module) should be fine? So not sure why this doesn't work.

Any help would be great

Comment: you need to provide more information. Tasks can be declared in the global space. So, your message is related to something else.

Comment: I don't have the LRMs in front of me, but I believe all versions of Verilog don't support declarations of signals, tasks, functions or parameters in the global space (ie outside of a module). I Know SystemVerilog does, however it is considered a bad practice to do so. The recommended was to defined commonly shared tasks, functions, etc. is to put them in a SystemVerilog package.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you're confusing Verilog2K ("Verilog") and SystemVerilog. In Verilog, task declarations can only appear inside modules or generates (and not 'globally'), which gives your error message. Second, your task contains two statements (the `begin/end` seq block and the timing control), which is not valid in Verilog; SV relaxes this. Having said that, putting the `#200` outside the block serves no purpose, so you might as well move it inside the block to make it Verilog-compatible.

Your next problem is that your task has no inputs or outputs - `x`, `y`, `z` are internal; you need to make them `input`, `output`, or `inout`.

Finally, you've cut/pasted incorrectly - this code won't compile without a couple more semicolons.